# MMC development in c#

Tags: c#, mmc

How can I provide the tool tip for my MMC Snapin scope node.
I am not bale to figure it out how to provide the tooltip functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I could find is an example where they explain how to build a resource dll which contains the icons and strings for the about box.

Not much else said there but there is a string **Description** not sure if it would work for both about box and also node tooltip.

http://www.mombu.com/microsoft/mmc/t-changing-about-box-in-mmc-30-snapin-917598.html